# XSLT-2.0: Combining results from current-group() into one

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

Using SaxonHE 9.7/XPath-2.0

My XML:

```
<osm>
  <node>
    <tag k="fhrs:id" v="204258"/>
    <tag k="name" v="King of Wessex"/>
  </node>
  <node>
    <tag k="fhrs:id" v="139245"/>
    <tag k="name" v="The Royal Oak"/>
  </node>
  <node>
    <tag k="fhrs:id" v="204258"/>
    <tag k="name" v="The Rising Sun"/>
  </node>
  etc...
</osm>
```

I'm returning all duplicated values (`v=`) of `fhrs:id`using:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">       
     <xsl:for-each-group select="/*/*/tag[@k='fhrs:id']" group-by="@v">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() [current-group()[2]]"/>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>
```

I'm transforming the output to geojson format. This requires every element, except the final one, to end with a comma. In other routines I've used this to test if it is the last:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/tag">
    {

     ...<snip>... 

    }<xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

However, because in this case the `xsl:apply-templates` is only passing two at a time, every other element is missing a comma in the geojson output.

Is there a way to combine all the outputs of `xsl:for-each-group`into one before passing it to `xsl:apply-templates` or an alternative way to find the final element? Is `xsl:for-each-group` even the best way to go about it?

I've looked into various way to use variables/arrays but do not appear to fit the bill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change

```
<xsl:template match="/">       
     <xsl:for-each-group select="/*/*/tag[@k='fhrs:id']" group-by="@v">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() [current-group()[2]]"/>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="/"> 
  <xsl:variable name="duplicates" as="element()*">      
     <xsl:for-each-group select="/*/*/tag[@k='fhrs:id']" group-by="@v">
        <xsl:sequence select="current-group() [current-group()[2]]"/>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$duplicates"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

As for the problem with `last()`, Saxonica has reproduced the problem reported in https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3122, I think in your case you can avoid using `last()` by using a slightly different check `position() gt 1`, but before outputting the content:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*/tag">
    <xsl:if test="position() gt 1">,</xsl:if>
    {

    "value" : "<xsl:value-of select="@v"/>"

    }
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <xsl:variable name="duplicates" as="element()*">      
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/*/*/tag[@k='fhrs:id']" group-by="@v">
            <xsl:sequence select="current-group() [current-group()[2]]"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$duplicates"/>
</xsl:template>
```

that way you should be able to avoid the bug associated with `last()` and nevertheless you should get a comma output between items of the sequence.

Comment: I had tried this previously & Saxon returns "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value of variable $duplicates (<tag/>, <tag/>, ...)"

Comment: @DaveF, sorry about that, the type is `element()*` for a sequence.

Comment: That worked, except last() was returning the total of **all** fhrs:id values not just the duplicated ones. So I passed the `duplicates` variable to the applied template:
  `<xsl:apply-templates select="$duplicates">
   <xsl:with-param name="duplicate" select = "$duplicates" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>`

and used it so:
  `}<xsl:if test="position() &lt; count($duplicate)">,</xsl:if>` Is the at the best wqay?

Comment: @DaveF, I am afraid the behaviour of Saxon 9.7 with the `last()` being wrong is a bug, it does not occur with 9.6. I have notified Saxonica with https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3122, let's see what they say.

Comment: @DaveF, I have added a workaround to avoid the problem with `last()`.